# Getting list of tests from Test Explorer in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, testing, coded-ui-tests, test-explorer

This is kind of a "high level"/simple question. I'm trying to get just a list of all the tests that are populated in my Test Explorer in VS2012. I'd like to compare it to a list of tests and I was wondering if there is any way to just get all the names out of the Test Explorer, like a copy/paste, export to csv or anything of that nature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select all tests in Test Explorer and add them to a playlist file. Playlist feature needs VS 2012 Update 2. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx#BKMK_Create_custom_playlists

Answer (score 9):

The exported playlist is in XML but I wanted a simple list. Here's a powershell script to strip off the XML syntax and print just the test names. I remove the namespace information from each test. If you'd like the full name, remove `$index = $child.Test.LastIndexOf(".")` and  `.Substring($index+1)`

`[xml] $content = get-content C:\out.xml
    $children = $content.SelectNodes("Playlist/Add")
    foreach($child in $children)
    {
         $index = $child.Test.LastIndexOf(".")
         Write-Output $child.Test.Substring($index+1)
    }`